# OnResume in react native screen of Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-state

I have a screen in react native for android.

I wanted to do some operation when particular screen(implemented in react-native) alone resumes as like fragment's onresume() in java/kotlin

How shall i achieve the fragment's onResume() concept in react native screen?

Searched and analysed some question in stack overflow. I see examples for APP state change but not the screen's state changes in react native.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using react-navigation you might use
`useFocusEffect`  -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Comment: Thanks Michael!, But i tried the useFocusEffect. but didnt get callback when specific screen comes to foreground from background.